# PowerShell Active Directory lastLogon/lastLogonTimestamp -- Empty lastLogon with populated lastLogonTimestamps

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I understand that lastlogon is stored per DC and that lastlogontimestamp is replicated but can be two weeks-ish off due to replication cycle.

I have a customer who wants the 'actual' last logon so I started writing a script to poll for all users' on each DC to compare their 'lastlogon' values, sort, and take the newest.  ...but I found something perplexing--I'm finding that across all DCs there are accounts that no DC has a record of authenticating (0/null value for lastlogon) but the account is showing a lastlogontimestamp value...

The environment is a forest-root domain with one child domain.  I originally started out just using:

```
@([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers.Name)
```

...but assumed that their AD Sites and Services might be jacked up -- it was the only thing I could come up with to provide a possible reason why no DC was showing a reported 'lastlogon' time but all were showing a 'lastlogontimestamp' value.  So, I started querying for:

```
@([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().GlobalCatalogs.Name)
```

...but ended up with the same results:  some accounts were reporting all zeros for lastlogon but showing actual timestamps for lastlogontimestamp!  wth?!

Can anyone clear up this madness for me?

```
$DCs         = @([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().DomainControllers.Name)
$DCs         = @([System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest().GlobalCatalogs.Name)
$LdapFilter  = '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'
$Properties  = 'distinguishedname','lastlogon','samaccountname','lastlogontimestamp'

$t = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
foreach ($dc in $DCs) {
    $s = [adsisearcher]"$LDAPFilter"
    $s.PageSize = 9999
    $s.SearchRoot = [adsi]"LDAP://$dc"
    [void] $s.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($Properties)

    $r = @($s.FindAll())

    if ($r.Count -gt 0) {
        $r | ForEach-Object {
            $temp = [pscustomobject]@{
                'samaccountname'     = $_.Properties['samaccountname'][0]
                'server'             = $dc
                'lastlogon'          = ([int64]$_.Properties['lastlogon'][0])
                'lastlogontimestamp' = ([int64]$_.Properties['lastlogontimestamp'][0])
            }

            [void]$t.Add($temp)
        }
    }
}

foreach ($g in ($t | Group-Object -Property samaccountname)) {
    $x = $g.Group | Sort-Object -Property lastlogon -Descending
    $x
}
```

Comment: sorry for the formatting, on the network i'm submitting this from, i don't have access to the formatting buttons on SO.

Comment: I do have to ask the dumb question. Were any domain controllers decommissioned after these accounts logged on?

Comment: As you already know, one attribute is replicated and one attribute is not. However, that is not the only difference between them. I believe LastLogon, for users, is when an account logs into a workstation or server joined to the domain. It would not update when someone accesses a file share or logs into webmail. That is when LastLogonTimeStamp would potentially update. Feel free to correct me if needed. Is it possible that these users never actually log into a domain-joined computer?

Comment: Yes, they should all be performing interactive keyboard authentications to a console session, sitting in front of a domain-joined machine directly connected to the network.

Comment: And to the question on decommissioned DCs--while that's a possibility, the lastlogontimestamps values are showing today's date...

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit JJJ.

Comment: AdminOfThings answer is relevant. Remember this is a "last known" value. It;s possible someone logged on to the domain long enough ago that the logs rolled over so there is no current LastLogon value in the logs (e.g. many users simply lock their workstations) When they make a network connection they'd receive a TimeStamp entry with no corresponding LastLogon value..

Comment: @Scepticalist "Logs rolled over"? Do you have a link to any documentation that shows that `lastLogon` is cleared when some logs roll over?

Comment: No, it's a slip of the keyboard as I deal with logs more than the current directory for this kind of thing. But the possibility remains.

Comment: I believe I found the culprit for my situation -- although if you have other odd cases where the timestamps are different, I'd love to read about them.  The customer is going through a migration and they have user-sync software keeping old-domain and new-domain user objects in sync.  Apparently the lastlogontimestamp value is being written to by the sync software on the new domain.  I've gotten the migration team to stop that and I'm going to wipe the lastlogontimestamp values and watch them to see if they exhibit the behavior again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code for that. Just use or adapt it to your needs.

```ps
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$properties = ("Name", "SamAccountName", "mail", "lastLogon", "manager", "company", "createTimeStamp", "department", "logonCount", "pwdLastSet", "userPrincipalName", "physicalDeliveryOfficeName", "employeeID", "accountExpires", "division", "msDS-ResultantPSO")
$users = @{}

foreach ($hostname in (Get-ADDomainController -Filter { IsReadOnly -eq $false } ).HostName) {
    foreach ($user in (Get-ADUser -Server $hostname -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -properties $properties | Select-Object $properties)) {
        if ( $users.Item($user.SamAccountName)) {
            If ( $user.lastLogon -gt $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon ) { $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).lastLogon = $user.lastLogon }
            $users.Item($user.SamAccountName).logonCount += $user.logonCount
        }
        else {
            $users.Add( $user.SamAccountName, $user )
        }
    }
}

$hostname = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -NextClosestSite).HostName
foreach ( $user in $users.Values ) {
    if ( $user.lastLogon ) { $user.lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.lastLogon) }
    if ( $user.pwdLastSet ) { $user.pwdLastSet = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.pwdLastSet) }
    if ( $user.accountExpires -eq "9223372036854775807" -or $user.accountExpires -eq "0" ) { $user.accountExpires = "never expires" }
    else {
        $user.accountExpires = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.accountExpires) 
    }
    if ( $user.manager ) { $user.manager = (Get-ADUser $user.manager -Server "$hostname" -properties Name ).Name }
}

$users.Values | Export-Csv -Path C:\ins\users.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```